# Azure openai 401 access denied invalid key or api endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I can run requests from Azure studio for gpt-35-turbo in western Europe zone. However any other way - postman, curl, python code, powershell - fails. Python code that run 48 hours ago now fails. The Azure status pages says all ok.

I can't go much wrong to test this because it's a copy paste from Studio, replacing the api key only. However I still checked and looked fine.

```
curl "https://<MYBASE>.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/<DEPLOYMENT>/chat/completions?api-version=2023-07-01-preview" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "api-key: YOUR_API_KEY" \
  -d "{
  \"messages\": [{\"role\":\"system\",\"content\":\"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information.\"}],
  \"max_tokens\": 800,
  \"temperature\": 0.7,
  \"frequency_penalty\": 0,
  \"presence_penalty\": 0,
  \"top_p\": 0.95,
  \"stop\": null
}"
```

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"401","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API
endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your
resource."}}
```

[image]